Auto-mount Google and Onedrive in Gnome on 24.04
I love the built-in linked accounts functionality in Gnome.
I connect to both my Google Drive and OneDrive accounts.
However, although they show up in Files (nautilus), they don't auto-mount.
I have to click on them to mount them after every restart.
How do I have them automatically mounted at logon?
PS - If you have the problem where OneDrive loses its credentials, then this is a great fix:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/05/fix-ubuntu-onedrive-account-error/amp

Did you find a solution?
